# Geopandas to_crs method end for no reason

Tags: python, geopandas

I was trying to reproject the Countries_WGS84.shp, its crs was originally epsg:4326, and I had tried this line of code:

```
GeoData.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})
```

However, when I execute to this line of code, the program just suddenly end for no reason!

Here is the entire code:

```
import geopandas as gpd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

GeoData = gpd.read_file('Countries_WGS84\Countries_WGS84.shp',encoding = 'big5-tw')

print(GeoData)
print("executed")
GeoData.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'}) 
print("non executed")

GeoData.plot()
plt.show()
```

And here is the result of execution:
 [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX7Ik.png)

It supposed to have popup of world boundaries map(with epsg:3857), but it seems that it just skipped the rest of the codes.

My python version is 3.7.3, and it seems that nobody has the same issue.

Does anyone know what's going on here? Really appreciate your help!

Comment: `to_crs` does not work inplace, you need to do `GeoData = GeoData.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})`, but that should not cause the error. If you try to plot without retrojecting, it works?

Comment: Problem solved. I had tried several times and found the reason why it doesn't work. It is the version of pyproj causing this problem. The original version was 2.X but after I switched it to 1.X, it works perfectly !